# git: how to "retrack" untracked file

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to git...

I untracked a file doing:

`git update-index --assume-unchanged filename`

Now I want to commit a change on this file, but I can't figure out how to remove the untrack.
I tried `git add filename` and `git update-index --add filename` thinking it was the way but it doesn't seem to work...

What's the command for this? I searched in the documentation and on the net, and maybe I just didn't use the right words... but I didn't find what I was looking for... I find git's documentation fairly hard to use as a newbie...

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simple:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged filename
```

I don't know where  you were looking, but both the flags are grouped together in the documentation:

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. Interestingly, it also looks like --assume-unchanged doesn't work anymore, though I've used it in the past (and now I want to undo it).